# Javascript loops running oddly

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to web development, and javascript.  In an attempt to make my website a little easier to maintain, I decided to use Javascript to make a 'navbar' read from a text file and add it to the top of each page.  What I am trying to do now, is create a function that allows me to specify a link, and a 'link depth', to return a relative link to my pages.  Here is the function:

```
 function increaseLinkDepth(aLink, aDepth) {
     var result = aLink;
     for(i = 0;i < aDepth;i++) {
         result = "../" + result;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Now, I have a bit of experience developing on the desktop and mobile devices, so this is a pretty simple function.  If I call the function like this: `/increaseLinkDepth("index.html", 1)`, I would expect to get the following result: `../index.html`.  I do get that when I run the javascript on the site.  Now, when I call the function in the following code:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i = 0;i < anchors.length;i++) {
        var lAnchor = anchors[i];
        var lAnchorLink = lAnchor.getAttribute("href");
        if(lAnchorLink.substring(0, 4) != "http") {
            var newLink = increaseLinkDepth(lAnchorLink, 1);
            //alert(newLink);
            lAnchor.setAttribute("href", newLink);
        }
    }
```

I end up in some kind of endless loop that causes me to have to restart my browser.  The links that it should be looking for are:

- index.html
- events.html
- about.html

It finds all three, but the loop happens on the about.html link.  I am not sure if I am missing something in my code (maybe been looking at it too long).  But I am not seeing where I am having this issue.

Now, I do understand that this may not be the best way to accomplish this, if it's not, please let me know, it's the only way that I could think to get a navbar created that I don't have to change the HTML for every single page.

Comment: Either have a server-side language generate correct links, or use absolute paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never declared `i` in either scope, so both loops are resetting the global `i` variable.

To avoid global pollution, be sure to wrap all of your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and add the `"use strict"` directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    ...your code here...
}());
```

The browser console would then tell you that you're using an undeclared variable in those scopes.

The sanitized version of your provided code would be:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    //variables declared at the top of the scope that they belong to
    var anchors,
        i,
        lAnchor,
        lAnchorLink,
        newLink;

    //function declarations follow variable declarations
    function increaseLinkDepth(aLink, aDepth) {
        var result,
            i;
        result = aLink;
        for (i = 0; i < aDepth; i++) {
            result = "../" + result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    //assignment and execution occurs after declarations
    anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        lAnchor = anchors[i];
        lAnchorLink = lAnchor.getAttribute('href');
        if (lAnchorLink.substring(0, 4) !== 'http') {
            newLink = increaseLinkDepth(lAnchorLink, 1);
            //alert(newLink);
            lAnchor.setAttribute("href", newLink);
        }
    }

    ...more code...
}());
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I depend on my IDEs (Visual Studio and Xcode) more than I thought I do.  I can't believe I made this simple mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using assigning to 'i' without declaring it as a local variable with var -- in JavaScript, this creates a global variable, which means both of your functions are using the same indexer.

Add a `var i;` to the top of each function and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget using the var keyword when you declare a variable, it will default to the global scope. In your case, the problem is with the i variable which in both methods refers to the same variable from the global scope. In short pseudocode, what you are doing is:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

Change your code to something along these lines:

```
function increaseLinkDepth(aLink, aDepth) {
     var result = aLink;
     for(var i = 0;i < aDepth;i++) {
         result = "../" + result;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var